# How do you use a COUNTIF with a Named Range in SUMPRODUCT with another filter?

Tags: arrays, excel, countif

Little tricky to explain in the title.

I have a Named Range called `Names` which contains the following values;

```
Dennis
Phillip
Sarah
```

I have a column with a list of names

```
  A
1 Michael
2 James
3 Dennis
4 Jessica
5 Phillip
```

Below is to count the times the name ranges appear
`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A10,Names))`=2

Now this is the tricky bit. `Column B` has their ages shown below.

```
A           B       
1 Michael   30    
2 James     15
3 Dennis    20
4 Jessica   22
5 Phillip   17
```

I now want to count all values in `Column A` which are in the named range `Names`, and are 18 or above.

In this example the resulting answer would be one.

I was hoping to just add this filter to `SUMPRODUCT` but it doesn't work.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A10,Names)*(B1:B10>17))
```

Comment: Thank you @QHarr, I've reworded it to make sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use COUNTIFS for multiple set of conditions and criteria:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A1:A5,Names,B1:B5,">17"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I just managed to work this out myself. Feel a little silly for not thinking of this. Would you know how to stimulate an OR filter in the same formula? i.e. if there was another column which had their address and they could either by over 18 OR from a certain country?